# Multiple instances of MSE7 open when I boot my computer

Tags: vbscript, gpo

I am running various VBS scripts on our clients using Group Policy.  On most clients this works fine.  But on my computer (the one I created the scripts on), I always have multiple instances of MSE7 running after booting my computer - one for each of the VBS scripts I have deployed via Group Policy.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and / or how to stop it!

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

With this script you can find any process by its commandline and choose to kill them. Just give a try !

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Copyright,fso,ws,NomFichierLog,temp,PathNomFichierLog,OutPut,Count
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
Copyright = "[© Hackoo © 2015 ]"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell" )
NomFichierLog="Killed_Process.txt"
temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
PathNomFichierLog = temp & "\" & NomFichierLog
Set OutPut = fso.CreateTextFile(temp & "\" & NomFichierLog,1)
    Call Find("wscript.exe")
    Call Explorer(PathNomFichierLog)
End If
'***************************************************************************************************
Function Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Explorer "& File & "\",1,True
end Function
'***************************************************************************************************
Sub Find(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Titre = " Process "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" running "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    Count = 0 
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Count= Count + 1
        Processus = objItem.CommandLine
        Question = MsgBox ("Would do you like to kill this script : " & DblQuote(Processus) & " ?" ,VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre+Copyright)
        If Question = VbYes then
            objItem.Terminate(0)'To kill the process
            OutPut.WriteLine Processus
        else
            Count= Count - 1 'decrementing the count of -1
        End if
    Next
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*")
OutPut.WriteLine count & Titre & "were killed"
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*") & VbCrLF 
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it does not really answer my questions which are (i) why do I only have the issue on one computer when the same scripts are running on all the clients, and (ii) is there some way in which I can modify the scripts to stop the problem happening.